# Why a click on svg element is not captured by node contains method?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a basic modal with a svg icon within its html structure. I want to detect clicks outside the modal so I can close it. The code to do so is something like the following:

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  if(modal.contains(e.target)) return;
  closeModal();
});
```

However, when I click on the svg (which inside the modal), the click event is considered to be outside the modal and I can't figure out why. To have it work as I want, I have to do pointer-events: none to the svg element.

The simplified html structure looks like this:

```
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="css-t7awl3">
      <form>
        <div class="css-1incodr">
          <label class="css-g2pzhe" for="previousPassword">
            Mot de passe actuel<span class="css-5fl39m">*</span>
          </label>
        <div class="css-1xm32e0">
          <input
            class="css-17lan49"
            type="text"
            placeholder="**********"
            name="previousPassword"
          />
            <div id="test-input-toggle-password-visibility" class="css-1vw18kh">
              <svg
                height="16"
                viewBox="0 0 32 32"
                fill="none"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="css-1pnrrva" disabled="">
          Valider
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Edit: Maybe it can help if I paste the actual react code here, as I am not sure if it's and issue with svg elements rather than my code.

```
    export const PasswordInput = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, PasswordInputProps>(({
  placeholder,
  name,
  id,
  disabled,
  className,
}: PasswordInputProps, ref) => {
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);

  const DisplayedPicto = showPassword ? ClosedEyePicto : EyePicto;

  return (
    <Container className={className}>
      <CustomInput
        className={className}
        type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        name={name}
        disabled={disabled}
        ref={ref}
        id={id}
      />
      <StyledSuffix
        onMouseLeave={() => setShowPassword(false)}
        onMouseDown={() => setShowPassword(true)}
        onMouseUp={() => setShowPassword(false)}
        id='test-input-toggle-password-visibility'
      >
        <DisplayedPicto height={16} />  //svg element
      </StyledSuffix>
    </Container>
  );
});
```

Comment: use [pointer-events="all"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events) for the svg element.

Comment: Thanks @enxaneta, but I don't want to use a trick (I already made it work with pointer-events: none). I want to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: If you used pointer-events:none then the click won't register on that element

Comment: empty svg elements or shapes with no fill do not respond to the mouse. You either need a fill or use  `pointer-events="all"

Comment: Can't reproduce this. See this example, clicks on the SVG are registered as "inside the modal": https://jsfiddle.net/35hzng89/  Which browser do you use?

Comment: @enxaneta The svg is empty here just for the sake of simplicity

Comment: @charlietfl Yes I know, and that's what I want to achieve here because I don't want the modal to close. Without pointer-events:none on the svg element itself, for some reason in my code the click ON the svg element is considered to be outside the modal.

Comment: @Sphinxxx I just edited my post to include my actual react code

Comment: Create a demo we can run this on and see the issue in browser dev tools. Can put one together quickly in codesandbox.io or stackblitz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just understood what was going on, and it has nothing to do with svgs.
What's happening is that when I click on the svg, first a 'mousedown' event is triggered. Remember that a 'click' event consists of 2 events following each other: first a 'mousedown' and then a 'mouseup'.

So with the 'mousedown' event on the svg, the onMouseDown event handler, on the component StyledSuffix surrounding my svg, is triggered. That leads to the svg on the dom actually changing from EyePicto to ClosedEyPicto (const DisplayedPicto = showPassword ? ClosedEyePicto : EyePicto;). Therefore, the modal no longer 'contains' the original svg since it has changed!

A solution is to listen to the click with the event 'click' rather than with 'mousedown'. Because the orginal svg (EyePicto) will only register the 'mousedown' event and not then 'mouseup' because it disappeared from the dom between the 2.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem, despite using a click event as OP suggested. The solution that finally worked for me was to apply `pointer-events: none` to the svg element inside the button, so that the SVG was never returned as the event target.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Been struggling with this for longer than I'd care to admit!

Comment: Great solution, I never considered that the svg inside of my link tag would be considered a target. For anyone using specific event target id's on say, clicking on an icon (where you need the line item id to identify particular data in your list), this solution will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The `Node.contains()` method might not behave as expected when dealing with SVG elements; the reason being that SVG elements and HTML elements are part of two different namespaces in the DOM. SVG elements are typically in the "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" namespace, while HTML elements are in the "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" namespace.

When you use `Node.contains()`, it operates within the same namespace as the parent element. If your dropdown's content includes both HTML and SVG elements, you may encounter issues when trying to check containment between these different namespaces.

As a solution, a more lengthy but reliable method than using `contains()` is to use `getBoundingClientRect()` to find the position of the containing element in the viewport, and compare this to the click event's `clientX`/`clientY` properties. Example:

```
const handleOutsideClick = (event) => {
  const containerRect = containerNode.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = event.clientX;
  const y = event.clientY;

  if (
    x < containerRect.left ||
    x > containerRect.right ||
    y < containerRect.top ||
    y > containerRect.bottom
  ) {
    outsideClickCallback();
  }
};
```

Comment: This "solution" is too generic and not specific to this particular issue